# index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0 Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**PLEASE READ:**
I have looked at all the other answers related to this question and none of them solve my specific problem so please carry on reading below.

I have the below code. what the code basically does is keeps the `Title` column and then concatenated the rest of the columns into one in order to be able to create a cosine matrix.

the main point is the `recommendations` function that is suppose to take in a Title for imput and return the top 10 matches based on that title but what i get at the end is the `index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0` error and i have no idea why.

```
import pandas as pd
from rake_nltk import Rake
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer




df = 
pd.read_csv('https://query.data.world/s/uikepcpffyo2nhig52xxeevdialfl7')

df = df[['Title','Genre','Director','Actors','Plot']]
df.head()

df['Key_words'] = ""

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    plot = row['Plot']

# instantiating Rake, by default it uses english stopwords from NLTK
# and discards all puntuation characters as well
r = Rake()

# extracting the words by passing the text
r.extract_keywords_from_text(plot)

# getting the dictionary whith key words as keys and their scores as values
key_words_dict_scores = r.get_word_degrees()

# assigning the key words to the new column for the corresponding movie
row['Key_words'] = list(key_words_dict_scores.keys())

# dropping the Plot column
df.drop(columns = ['Plot'], inplace = True)


# instantiating and generating the count matrix
df['bag_of_words'] = df[df.columns[1:]].apply(lambda x: ' 
'.join(x.astype(str)),axis=1)
count = CountVectorizer()
count_matrix = count.fit_transform(df['bag_of_words'])

# generating the cosine similarity matrix
cosine_sim = cosine_similarity(count_matrix, count_matrix)
cosine_sim



indices = pd.Series(df.index)

#  defining the function that takes in movie title 
# as input and returns the top 10 recommended movies
def recommendations(title, cosine_sim = cosine_sim):
    #print(title)
    # initializing the empty list of recommended movies
    recommended_movies = []

    # gettin the index of the movie that matches the title
    idx = indices[indices == title].index[0]
    print('idx is '+ idx)

    # creating a Series with the similarity scores in descending order
    score_series = pd.Series(cosine_sim[idx]).sort_values(ascending = False)

    # getting the indexes of the 10 most similar movies
    top_10_indexes = list(score_series.iloc[1:11].index)

    # populating the list with the titles of the best 10 matching movies
    for i in top_10_indexes:
        recommended_movies.append(list(df.index)[i])

    return recommended_movies
```

Comment: idx = indices[indices == title].index[0] check what this line is doing

Comment: `indices[indices == title]` looks fishy. That is a comparison, evaluating to `True` or `False`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
idx = indices[indices == title].index[0]
```

will fail if you do not return a match:

```
df.loc[df['Title']=='This is not a valid title'].index[0]
```

returns:

`IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0`

You need to confirm that the title you are passing in is actually in DF before trying to access any data associated with it:

```
def recommendations(title, cosine_sim = cosine_sim):
    #print(title)
    # initializing the empty list of recommended movies
    recommended_movies = []

    if title not in indices:
        raise KeyError("title is not in indices")

    # gettin the index of the movie that matches the title
    idx = indices[indices == title].index[0]
    print('idx is '+ idx)

    # creating a Series with the similarity scores in descending order
    score_series = pd.Series(cosine_sim[idx]).sort_values(ascending = False)

    # getting the indexes of the 10 most similar movies
    top_10_indexes = list(score_series.iloc[1:11].index)

    # populating the list with the titles of the best 10 matching movies
    for i in top_10_indexes:
        recommended_movies.append(list(df.index)[i])

    return recommended_movies
```

This expression also seems to be doing nothing:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    plot = row['Plot']
```

If you just want a single plot record with which to do some development try:

```
plot = df['Plot'].sample(n=1)
```

Finally, it appears that `recommendations` is using the global variable `indices` - in general this is bad practice, as if `indices` changes outside of the scope of `recommendations` the function might break. I would consider refactoring this to be a little less brittle overall.

Comment: it seems that it is the `indices` variable causing the issue as if i look at `indices.head() ` it returns numbers that match the actual index when what it should return is the movie title.... any thoughts that might help me?

Comment: Well, a couple issues: 


`indices = pd.Series(df.index)`


is working as intended. `df` has a `RangeIndex`, meaning it's a monotonically increasing series of integers, one integer per row. You want: 


`indices = df.loc[:, 'Title']`


But even that is not what you want. You want to pass df in as an argument to `recommendations`, or have `recommendations` be a method on a class with `df` in its scope and then index on df directly:


`idx = df.loc[df['Title'] == title].index[0]`